# Convert the date into an individual date and time in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I would like to convert a date that I have in R into an individual date and time. At the moment the format of the date is `POSIXct`

An example is given here:

```
"2019-03-29 20:42:07"
```

I want the date to be in one column and the time of that date in a corresponding column. I have found something similar [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-with-error-in-as-posixlt-character-x-tz-tz-x-character-string-is-not-in-a-standard-unambiguous-format/36643), but it doesn't answer my question. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column shows `POSIXct` class.  Create two new columns by coercing to `Date` (`as.Date`) and the time part with `format`

```
df1 <- transform(df1, date = as.Date(datetime), time = format(datetime, "%T"))
df1
#           datetime       date     time
#1 2019-03-29 20:42:07 2019-03-30 20:42:07
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(1553910127, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```